# Android change Dialog background color from app settings via styles

Tags: android, xml, android-preferences, android-styles

I want to change default Dialog background color of my PreferenceActivity (Dialog that opens where we choose option from list in settings). Now the background of Dialog is always white although I change it in my styles. I am trying to solve that like in my code but it does not work. Here are my light and dark styles.

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme_ObjectMeasure_Light" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogThemeLight</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/DialogThemeLight</item>

    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bottom_nav_view_bg_night</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme_ObjectMeasure_Dark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogThemeDark</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/DialogThemeDark</item>

    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bottom_nav_view_bg_night</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ThemeActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogThemeLight" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bg_light</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogThemeDark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bg_dark</item>
</style>
```

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    (...)
    <color name="bg_light">#E0E0E0</color>
    <color name="bg_dark">#424242</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read that on a newer devices the attributes with android: prefix should be used or to use AppCompat theme as a parent to get rid of confusing with this prefix.